# Combine Elevation Raster and MultilineString to create MultilineStringZ in PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, raster, elevation

I want to show how steep a given stream is, with PostGIS and QGIS.

My thought process for solving this problem of steepness is as follows:
1). Given Raster and Multilinestring data, combine them into a MultilineStringZ column
2). Perform some elementary calculus on the new MultilineStringZ column to find steeper sections. Colorize them in QGIS if possible to examine the results.

Elevation Data:

[image: Elevation Data of Minnesota]

Stream Data as MultilineString:

[image: Stream data in Minnesota]

I need a better understanding on how a MultilineString and a raster layer are combined to create a 3D stream, or alternatives to completing the task of encoding "steepness" into line strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a MultiLineStringZ from raster and MultiLineString, use the [ST_Intersection](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Intersection.html) function or [ST_Value](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Value.html) (combined with [ST_Segmentize](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Segmentize.html)).

You can also compute steepnesses right in raster space using the [ST_Slope](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Slope.html) function.

[Examples of using ST_Value](http://www.postgis.us/chapter_12_edition_2).

Comment: By sheer coincidence, I had the MEAP 2nd edition in my drop box. Thanks for your hard work.  However, it seems that using ST_Intersection creates many different LineStrings and Multiline strings, like pushing a piece of spaghetti through a screen door. Now I have about 300+ pieces of macaroni. Is there a way to ensure that one single geometry results in a single MultilineStringZ?

Comment: Usually for LineStrings, I go the ST_Segmentize approach (think we have that covered in the book as well) which better handles this issue.  ST_Segmentize will add more nodes to your line, and then you take the ST_Value at each node and reconstruct the linestring from these.  So its less accurate than ST_Intersection, but you won't run into the meat grinder problem.

Comment: I used the following code successfully that can be found in Chapter 12 of PostGIS in Action, 2nd Edition: http://pastebin.com/wdKfRU7q

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer for transforming a LineString column `geog` into a LineStringZ by adding Z values from a raster table called `elevations`:

```
WITH points2d AS (
  SELECT gid,
         ST_DumpPoints(geog::geometry) AS point2d -- Split the LineString into points
  FROM lines
),
linestrings3d AS (
  SELECT gid,
         ST_MakeLine( -- Combine the points into LineStringZ
           ST_Translate( -- Add the Z value
             ST_Force3DZ((point2d).geom), -- Force the points to 3D
             0,
             0,
             ST_Value( -- Extract the Z value from the raster
               rast,
               (point2d).geom
             )
           ) ORDER BY (point2d).path -- Ensure the points keep their initial order
         ) AS linestringz
  FROM points2d
    LEFT JOIN elevations ON ST_Intersects(rast, (point2d).geom) -- Only use the raster rows containg information for those points
  GROUP BY gid
)
UPDATE lines
SET geog = linestringz -- Update the original column from 2D to 3D
FROM linestrings3d
WHERE lines.gid = linestrings3d.gid;
```